# updating speacial characters into database

Tags: sql

I have string with many & and | operators . If I try to update such a string into database it asks me for a value . For e.g if i try to update a string  A&B oracle asks me for a value .
I want to store the string as A&B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have this problem using SQL*Plus as a client, you should first give this command:

set define off

With set define you can also change the substitution character (&).

Answer (score 2):

You can also define an escape character and use it, for example:

SET ESCAPE '\'

SELECT 'A\&B' FROM companies;